# Value of this shows  different results when event handlers are assigned in two different ways

Tags: javascript, events, setattribute

See my code
http://jsfiddle.net/kxATT/3/

```
           function byId(id) {
               if (id) {
                   return document.getElementById(id);
               } else {
                   return null;
               }
           }

           function setAttr(elm, attr, value) {
               elm.setAttribute(attr, value);
           }

           var app = {
               id: 12,
               fn: function () {
                   alert(this.id);
               }
           };

           function init() {
               setAttr(byId('txt'), 'onclick', 'app.fn()');
               byId('txt1').addEventListener('click', app.fn, true);
           }
```

When the first box is clicked,it alerts `12`. And for the second box it alers `txt1`. Obviously in both cases although I'm calling the same function, `this` refers to different objects. I've heared that, for input elements,the element's object  itself is passed to the function and reffered as `this` inside the event handler function. If so why is it not true when events are added using setAttribute.

Comment: `app.fn()`.... inside this function, `this` will refer to `app`. [Read more about `this` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). It's true that `this` refers to element in the event handler. Try `setAttr(byId('txt'), 'onclick', 'console.log(this);app.fn()');`. The content of the string `'app.fn()'` is the event handler's body, so there `this` will refer to the element. But `app.fn()` is just a function you call *from* the event handler, and the context never "carries" over (unless you use `.call()` or `.apply()`).

Comment: thanks for that link...Its new information to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign a string to `onclick`, you're basically creating the *body* of a function; the browser supplies the function, e.g. your string `"app.fn()"` becomes:

```
function onclickHandlerCreatedByBrowser(event) {
    app.fn();
}
```

When you assign a function reference via `addEventListener`, as with any time you use a function reference with JavaScript, it's *just* a function reference; there is no object information. `this` in JavaScript is set entirely by how a function is called, not where it's defined.

If you're using an ECMAScript5-enabled environment (or using an ES5 shim), you can solve this using [`Function#bind`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4.5):

```
byId('txt1').addEventListener('click', app.fn.bind(app), true);
```

Otherwise, you can solve it by supplying the function that the browser provides in the string case yourself:

```
byId('txt1').addEventListener('click', function() {
    app.fn();
}, true);
```

More reading:

- [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

Comment: +1 Good links, I think I've read that author's work before somewhere... :P

Answer (score 2):

The `this` context is the object in one event handler and the `input` element in the other, of which the `id` property corresponds to the the `input` element's `id` attribute.